# Analogue multiplexer using JFET for small signals

Tags: amplifier, switches, jfet, multiplexer

I'm working on a circuit with a non-inverting amp and I would like to switch between two reference voltages, both with low output impedance.

So in effect i want something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0HWmT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One thing: R1 is done using LM385 low power reference voltage, so voltage between anode and katode of D1 is 1.2V.
Output impedance of U1 is about 300 ohms.

I stumbled upon a thing called analog multiplexer and I think that it would suit this purpose quite OK. I would like to build it using basic components instead of buying IC. I thought about using JFETs, but would it make sense for such small voltages?

Please help!:)

Comment: Please post the schematic of the circuit you're proposing to use to implement an analog multiplexer using JFETs.

Comment: In principle, yes you can. Are you as far along as having a circuit yet? If so, please edit your question and add the circuit to it. Or are you right at the start, just wondering if it's even a good idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why use two references when apparently one would suffice with a pot divider?

Comment: @Andyaka Alright, I added more detailed schematic:) It is a part of a more complex circuit. What I need right now is just to make this mux, preferably using basic ocmponents such as JFETs:) I'm pretty much sure that it is a good idea. Is it possible?

Comment: I think the best idea is use a chip.

Comment: @TonyM I have a circuit, I have added a more detailed scheme to the question. I have just figured out that on the first stage of amplification I need to switch between low signal (microVolts range p2p with offset) and constant reference voltage, this is why I'm asking for help:)

Comment: @Andyaka Do you have any suggestions about the chip?

Comment: There are plenty of analogue switches and multiplexers to be found from all the major suppliers. Watch out for leakage currents creating an offset error and watch out for off capacitance still letting high frequencies through.

Comment: @Andyaka Alright, thanks. I'm thinking about CD4051, but I can't find output impedance of this chip. Is this parameter even available in datasheets of muxes?

Comment: The output impedance is the on resistance plus the source impedance. Think of it like a relay contact but with appreciable on resistance.